# How to convert the JSON array into dictionary of key value pairs

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I have a dynamic Json. from that json I have converted that json into

var mainjson = (IDictionary)SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(received);

dictionary of key value pairs

Now I get json Array from
 var secjson = mainjson["feelingLucky"];

now the secjson is a Json Array now I want to convert it into Dictionary of key Value Pairs. Is it possible in wp8 to convert json Array into Dictionary??

Comment: Can you post sample json value?

Answer (score 1):

You already deserialized your received json into IDictionary. So now mainjson["feelingLucky"] should be having key value pair if it was correctly formatted in Json object "received".

Can you post the sample structure of your "received".

Comment: this is my json structure